# Remove null from interface properties

Tags: typescript

I have a few interfaces that describe the structure of a deep object. Something like:

```js
interface IBar {
  a: string | null;
  b: number | null;
}

interface IBaz {
  c: string | null;
  d: boolean | null;
}

interface IFoo {
  bar: IBar;
  baz: IBaz;
}
```

Currently, for each property, I am using the non-null assertion operator, like `obj.bar.a!`. To avoid doing this everywhere I need to access a property, I'd like a way to create a new interface which "removes" the `null` from the "leaf" interfaces.

In other words, I'd like to do:

```js
const obj: DoMagic<IFoo> = getObj();
```

so that the type becomes:

```js
{
  bar: {
    a: string;
    b: number;
  },
  baz: {
    c: string;
    d: boolean;
  }
}
```

---

So far I've only found solutions for `DeepPartial` which, I think, does the exact opposite of what I need. `NonNullable` seems relevant, but I'd like to apply it to the root interface, rather than on each leaf. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible by using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet) type utility.

**One level** deep version:

```
type NoNullFields<Ob> = { [K in keyof Ob]: NonNullable<Ob[K]> };
type NoNullIBar = NoNullFields<IBar>;
```

**NoNullFields** type constructor is creating a type which has the same keys as the given one `[K in keyof Ob]` but values have types with excluded `null` possibility by `NonNullable<Ob[K]>`

---

**Recursive version** (works with nested structures):

```
type NoNullFields<Ob> = { [K in keyof Ob]: Ob[K] extends object 
? NoNullFields<Ob[K]> : NonNullable<Ob[K]> };
type NoNullIBar = NoNullFields<IBar>;
```

Most important is this part - `Ob[K] extends object ? NoNullFields<Ob[K]> : NonNullable<Ob[K]>`. It means that if the field is an object then we recursively use our type constructor on it, if not we set field as NonNullable.

Comment: Interesting. What if the object is of variable depth, is there a way to do some recursive checking? The reality is that my example is a simplification and that the object can be 4 or 5 levels deep.